# How to force logout user when his/her username is changed by another user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In my application I am using Forms-Authentication to sign in and sign out users.

One functionality is admin can change the username of other users. In that case, I need to sign out the user whose username is changed.

If I do not, due to their cookies set before, they gain access to application and receive error messages (since their username does not exist and there are parts where I use their username for some functionality).

How can I force these users to log out using Forms-Authentication ?

**UPDATE :**

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action     = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(); ;
        // Below returns the previous username, which does not exist anymore in db.
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        if (!unitOfWork.UserRepository.UserExists(userName))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
            // I am not using Roles.


        }
        unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
```

In my customer global filter, I check whether user exist or not, if not I sign them out. However, it is not working. By working I mean they pass the authentication and gain access to application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what you do to force user to sign out:

```
public void UserPasswordChangedHandler()
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  Roles.DeleteCookie();
  Session.Clear();
}
```

I don't think line by line explanation required, its self explanatory enough.
Please let me know if I am mistaken.

**Update**

Straightforward answer to your additional question is to keep per user boolean tracking if his data was updated by admin and if yes - just redirect him to login page.

Please see following articles for forced logout using forms authentication information:

- [How can I force a user to log out](http://forums.asp.net/t/1839900.aspx/1)
- [How can I force a log out of all users for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488547/how-can-i-force-a-log-out-of-all-users-for-a-website),
- [ASP.NET forms authentication forced logout](http://forums.asp.net/t/1623873.aspx/1)
- [How to log off multiple MembershipUsers that are not the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600109/how-to-log-off-multiple-membershipusers-that-are-not-the-current-user)

**Update 2**

Clearing cookies

- [HowTo: create and remove Cookies with ASP.NET MVC](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [How do you clear cookies in ASP NET MVC 3 and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122404/how-do-you-clear-cookies-using-asp-net-mvc-3-and-c)
- [How do I invalidate a bad authentication cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419880/how-do-i-invalidate-a-bad-authentication-cookie-early-in-the-request)

Hope this help you.

Comment: i think this signs out the user logged in. I want to sign out other users, whose password is changed by admin. Well, i can certainly use this code to sign that user to log out but how can i understand, their password is changed? in other words when this method should be called ?

Comment: Glad the code I provided was of help. To answer your additional question (how to handle), please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I use your code in my custom ActionFilterAttribute filter. There, I check whether username exist or not, if it does not (this condition satisfied when I change my own username), I sign the user out. However, problem persists. User's cookie stays and he gains access to application. Any ideas ? I updated my question with filter code.

Comment: Try this: `this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Clear();`

Comment: Update 2 in the answer. They all successfully deleting cookies, no reason you not able to.

Comment: still not working, but it should be. probably i am doing something else wrong. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

When a user needs to become invalidated you must add their details to some kind of internal static list.

Then on every page request (possibly using Application_BeginRequest) see if that current user is in that list, and if so to call FormsAuthentication.SignOut there-and-then.

It seems like a bit of a hack, but it's the best I can think of right now.

Note that removing a user-in-absentia's session state is another issue entirely.

Comment: we do a similar thing to stop multiple users logging on from different machines, we generate a token (based on the users pc information) for each login and then check if that token is the same, if not we force a signout